# How to automate existing windows Form based application using autoit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, automation, autoit

I want to use automated testing using autoit for my existing windows form based application. Currently looking at the autoit documentation I couldnt figure out how to start a existing windows application in vb.net and then use it for further automation.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the application you are testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting an application via Autoit:

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm

Starting an application via VB.NET:

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/prstrt.htm

Comment: The AutoIt notepad tutorial is the perfect way to get started in this way as it is almost identical to what sam wants.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think Autoit can invoke a .NET assembly so you will have to make your .net assembly COM Visible, and expose any functions you want to test using COM.

[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248) is about calling .NET assemblies from VB6 but the process is the same.

However I would love to know why you want to use AutoIt to automate testing when you could do anything that autoit can do (and more) in .NET?

Comment: I have an existing windows forms based project, what I want is to do automation testing of that project. Just found open source autoit that can handle this but couldn't figure out how. As autoit is creating everything instead of using the existing one's. Still looking for solutions

Comment: If you don't have visual studio then you can install [visual studio express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic) which is free?

Answer (score 0):

Did it by just calling the exe of that project Run("Z:\test\WindowsServices.Test\bin\Debug\WindowsServices.exe")

Answer (score 0):

```
Run("\\covmqaap01\CRE\CREST.exe")

Sleep(5000)

ControlClick( "CREST :: Login", "", 4 )

Sleep(3000)

; Login Details

ControlSend( "CREST :: Login", "", 4, "Ramana" )

Sleep(3000)

Send("{TAB 1}")

Sleep(3000)

ControlSend( "CREST :: Login", "", 3, "ramana@123" )

Sleep(2000)

ControlClick( "CREST :: Login", "", 1 )

Sleep(20000)
```